# My code doesn't go through the else statement

Tags: android

My code checks `if mode="search" true` when it goes in second activity. If so, then `School_name` is this value, otherwise the value is set when the user clicks an `ImageView` or `ListView`.

The problem is that if i click form imageview is return true this statement `if (( mode.compareTo("search")==0) )` and get value from `if (( mode.compareTo("search")==0) )` if is flase not go else statement tell me what is wrong in my code

```
public class HomeMenu extends Activity {

    public static String mode;
    editText2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    imageView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v){
            mode = "search";
            Intent iMenuList = new Intent(HomeMenu.this, SecondStep.class);
            Serachvalue = editText2.getText().toString();
            iMenuList.putExtra("Serachvalue", Serachvalue);
            startActivity(iMenuList);
        }
    });

    listMainMenuhome=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMainMenuhome);

    listMainMenuhome.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick (AdapterView < ? > arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3){
            Intent iMenuList = new Intent(HomeMenu.this, SecondStep.class);
            iMenuList.putExtra("School_name", Category_name.get(position));

            startActivity(iMenuList);
        }
    });
```

```
public class SecondStep extends Activity {
    String mode;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.secondstep);

        mode = HomeMenu.mode;
        if ((mode.compareTo("search") == 0)) {
            Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
            School_name = bundle.getString("Serachvalue");
        } else {
            Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
            School_name = bundle.getString("School_name");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: pls fomart your code.

Comment: my code goes perfectly on second activity if clickon imageview but if i clickon listview is show error not go else statement tellme what is wrong incode???

Comment: post the stacktrace or atleast state the error

Comment: Try to set braking point on `mode=HomeMenu.mode;`. Post what you see

Comment: in secondstep.class if more is not"Search" is not go in else statement in debug mode why???

Comment: if i click on imageview mode=HomeMenu.mode; show"search" but why my code not go else statement if i click on listview?

Comment: what is the actual value of `mode` ?

Comment: as @MaximShoustin suggested I would debug this alot more, for example what does `mode.compareTo("search")` result in each time. create a local variable `int` and use that within the if statement whilst debugging...

Comment: you might want to use mode.equals("search") instead

Comment: Why are you using `compareTo`? It does a lexicographic string comparison and that doesn't seem to be what you want here. Do you just want `equals`? Also, is there a reason your mode is a String? Why not have an enum?

Comment: if you are using **custom `compareTo`** the problem is there

Comment: i want to check user click from imageview or listview

Answer (score 2):

listMainMenuhome.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
    int position, long arg3) {
    mode="";
     Intent iMenuList = new Intent(HomeMenu.this, SecondStep.class);
        iMenuList.putExtra("School_name", Category_name.get(position));


    startActivity(iMenuList);

        }
    });
```

---

```
   mode=HomeMenu.mode;
if (mode.equalsIgnoreCase("search"))            
{   
      Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
 School_name = bundle.getString("Serachvalue");             
}       
else
{           
      Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
      School_name = bundle.getString("School_name");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set mode empty in list event handler.

```
mode = "";
```

Comment: this code work now

String  s2="search";
  mode=HomeMenu.mode;
  if(mode.equals(s2.toString()))  
      {